# Visual Studio 2012 professional stops running

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012 Professional stopped running after reinstalling (there is no error message or any other message given). Re-reinstallation has not given any result. Also there is one oddity: the installer doesn't allow me to change the installation path (field is disabled). How do I fix this?

My OS is Windows 8, and the image of Visual Studio is downloaded from Dreamspark.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you need to start from scratch again - and I assume that will help.
- First, [uninstall visual studio completely](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441).
- Then [uninstall .NET FW (completely)](http://djlab.com/2010/10/how-to-completely-uninstall-net-framework/), maybe with the use of the cleanup tool.
- When you are done, restart your system.
- Find and remove any files that still physically present on your system (on VS install path, common files, %appdata%, etc)
- Open registry editor and search for any possible orphans/leftovers (e.g. search for "visual studio", "studio 2012", "visual " and any other 'keywords' you may find throughout your search)
- Use a registry cleaner tool. E.g. by selecting one from [this list](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/free-registry-cleaner-programs.htm).
- Restart your system again (even if nothing indicates you need to!)
- Test if you still have any leftovers (e.g. try to run an app. that needs .NET FW), clean if you do.
- Reinstall Visual Studio
If you still experience problems after this, the VS issues are the consequences of something else. E.g. you installed an app which "disturbs" VS's working. In this case, you need to recall what did you do/install after VS and when the problems started.
Worst case scenario you'll need to reinstall the OS (or try first the repair option, as well as rolling back to a previous restore point) and see what happens after installing applications, one by one (install VS, test. install another app, test VS, and so on)